# Duplicate Fields within Duplicate Groups jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, duplicates

Does anyone know how to duplicate a field in a duplicated group?
I tried it with recopy jQuery but it did not work as expected.

This are my Clone Fields:
If i klick on add Text1 it should clone the duplicable fields.
But its duplicating only the removelink!
Hope this info was enough for you.

```js
$(function(){
var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">Delete</a>';

$('a.add').relCopy({ append: removeLink});
});

/**
 * jQuery-Plugin "relCopy"
 * 
 * @version: 1.1.0, 25.02.2010
 * 
 * @author: Andres Vidal
 *          code@andresvidal.com
 *          http://www.andresvidal.com
 *
 * Instructions: Call $(selector).relCopy(options) on an element with a jQuery type selector 
 * defined in the attribute "rel" tag. This defines the DOM element to copy.
 * @example: $('a.copy').relCopy({limit: 5}); // <a href="example.com" class="copy" rel=".phone">Copy Phone</a>
 *
 * @param: string excludeSelector - A jQuery selector used to exclude an element and its children
 * @param: integer limit - The number of allowed copies. Default: 0 is unlimited
 * @param: string append - HTML to attach at the end of each copy. Default: remove link
 * @param: string copyClass - A class to attach to each copy
 * @param: boolean clearInputs - Option to clear each copies text input fields or textarea
 * 
 */

(function($) {

 $.fn.relCopy = function(options) {
  var settings = jQuery.extend({
   excludeSelector: ".exclude",
   emptySelector: ".empty",
   copyClass: "copy",
   append: '',
   clearInputs: true,
   limit: 0 // 0 = unlimited
  }, options);
  
  settings.limit = parseInt(settings.limit);
  
  // loop each element
  this.each(function () {
   
   // set click action
   $(this).click(function (){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); // rel in jquery selector format    
    var counter = $(rel).length;
    
    // stop limit
    if (settings.limit != 0 && counter >= settings.limit){
     return false;
    };
    
    var master = $(rel+":first");
    var parent = $(master).parent();      
    var clone = $(master).clone(true).addClass(settings.copyClass+counter).append(settings.append);
    
    //Remove Elements with excludeSelector
    if (settings.excludeSelector){
     $(clone).find(settings.excludeSelector).remove();
    };
    
    //Empty Elements with emptySelector
    if (settings.emptySelector){
     $(clone).find(settings.emptySelector).empty();
    };        
    
    // Increment Clone IDs
    if ( $(clone).attr('id') ){
     var newid = $(clone).attr('id') + (counter +1);
     $(clone).attr('id', newid);
    };
    
    // Increment Clone Children IDs
    $(clone).find('[id]').each(function(){
     var newid = $(this).attr('id') + (counter +1);
     $(this).attr('id', newid);
    });
    
    //Clear Inputs/Textarea
    if (settings.clearInputs){
     $(clone).find(':input').each(function(){
      var type = $(this).attr('type');
      switch(type)
      {
       case "button":
        break;
       case "reset":
        break;
       case "submit":
        break;
       case "checkbox":
        $(this).attr('checked', '');
        break;
       default:
         $(this).val("");
      }      
     });     
    };
    
    $(parent).find(rel+':last').after(clone);
    
    return false;
    
   }); // end click action
   
  }); //end each loop
  
  return this; // return to jQuery
 };
 
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="clone1"> 
<p class="clone"> 

<label for="beschreibung">Wähle:</label>
  <select name="Wähle[]">
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="2">2</option> 
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select><br />

<label for="beschreibung">Text:</label><textarea type="text" rows="5" cols="48" name="Text[]" /></textarea><br /><br />
</p>

<p><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">add Text</a></p>

</p>

<p><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone1">add Text1</a></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please visit [help] to see how to ask questions

Comment: You'll need to show the code you tried, otherwise it's impossible to say what's wrong with it.

Comment: I have add the code I have tried ;)

Comment: html is invalid, can't nest `<p>` as child of another `<p>`

Comment: and what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use inline event handlers with jQuery if you can avoid it. It separates your *event registration* from the *event handler* for no reason (and you miss out on other cool jQuery event features). Use *delegated event handlers*, attached to a non-changing ancestor element, if items are added dynamically.

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e){
    e.preventdefault();
    $(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() });
});
```

This listens for the event to bubble up to document (which is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient). It then applies the jQuery selectors, so the items only need to match at event time! Great for dynamic elements.

2. You can't nest paragraph tags. I replaced them with divs (which can be nested) for the example.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbz9b61c/

3. Your actual solution is hard to determine as you are cloning existing items and not hidden/template items. This means you are potentially cloning clones and multiple clones at that. If you can explain the *end result* more clearly I may be able to offer a cleaner suggestion :)